# File permissions with Laravel on Docker - can't edit file

Tags: laravel, docker, file-permissions, permission-denied, user-permissions

I'm running a fresh installation of Laravel on Docker.

When I run the container and try to access the laravel app from the browser I get this error that Laravel throws on screen for the file permissions

```
UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2019-02-24.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

So, if I do while I'm in the running container `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/` and switch the ownership of the files to the `www-data` user the erros is gone and I can see the default page as expected. The problem is that I cannot write / edit any of the files of the app and make changes in the code base.

If I `sudo chown -R lykos:lykos ./application // the folder that my laravel app lives in` from my local terminal (i.e. not through the running container) I can edit the files, but the error for file permissions is showing again.

How can I fix this? Btw I'm on Linux, so I think this error is not occuring for windows or mac users. Also I want try to avoid the common `chmod 777` solution as it is not recommended as a proper solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is changing the permission of the mounted directory from the host itself so for example if you have the following directory on the host `/home/lykos/laravel/data` and you need to mounted it inside a docker container follow the following:

- Check the `UID` and `GID` inside the container which is used to make
  laravel running for example you may find both `UID` and `GID` with
  the following value `1000` then from the host run the following
  command `chown 1000:1000 /home/lykos/laravel/data`

Now the laravel application should be able to write inside whatever directory you use it as a destination for `/home/lykos/laravel/data` and make sure that you don't modify it without confirming that you have the correct permission e.g. don't create another directory inside it manually unless you do `chown` after creating it.

The above solution works for the user that will be used to write to that directory if there are other users you need to make sure to give them a proper permission maybe through linux acl instead of using world permission (777)

Let say you have a container as a webserver and you need to keep the application hosted inside the container while developing from your localhost. Assuming the localhost user that is used for development is `lykos` and the container user which is used by the webserver is `33` for `UID` and `GID` you can do the following from your localhost:

```bash
sudo chown 33:33 /home/lykos/laravel/data -R
sudo setfacl -Rm u:lykos:rwx,d:u:lykos:rwx /home/lykos/laravel/data
```

The above command will gives the webserver the ability to access and update the project files. and also gives your localhost the ability to modify the current files and newly created files (note that if you have create any file or directory using `lykos` user you need to make `chown` to match the webserver uid)

Comment: If I do `sudo chown lykos:lykos /home/lykos/my-laravel-app` the ownership if I do ls -la is `lykos lykos` and I can edit the files. Then if I do `docker-compose run --rm app bash` and ls -la I have this `1000 1000` as you said. But when I try to access the app from the browser I get the file permission error. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Maybe another user tries to access the files, Does the webserver use the same user that has uid equal to 1000 ?

Comment: How can I check this? if I switch to www-data:www-data in the container the error is not showing, but also can't edit the files

Comment: So it seems that www-data uid is not equal to 1000. run the following command from the container: `id -u www-data` what is the result ?

Comment: Its different, its 33

Comment: So that is the issue, your localhost uid is 1000 (which you use to write on the file during the development) and the container user is 33 which the container use to access the files of your application. So i suggest to change it to 33:33 and then set an acl for your localhost user so you can write to the files

Comment: Run the following commands from the localhost terminal: `chown 33:33 /home/lykos/laravel/data -R && setfacl -m u:lykos:rw /home/lykos/laravel/data`

Comment: Still can't edit the files, I get a permission denied on my editor

Comment: what about adding execute so you can list the files ? 
`setfacl -Rm u:lykos:rwx /home/lykos/laravel/data`

Comment: Yep, this seems to work! Do you want to update your answer so I can approve it? thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm having again the same issue, but when I run the last command you gave me I get this error `Operation not permitted` and if I try to edit a file and save it, it pops an authentication window. Any further suggestions please?

Comment: What about the command that in the answer?  It will set a default acl on the future files and directories

Comment: I've run both `sudo chown 33:33 /home/lykos/mylaravelapp/application -R && setfacl -m u:lykos:rwx /home/lykos/mylaravelapp/application` and  `sudo chown 33:33 /home/lykos/mylaravelapp/application -R && setfacl -m u:lykos:rwx,d:u:lykos:rwx /home/lykos/mylaravelapp/application` but getthe same error

Comment: Which folder is causing the issue ? and what is the current permission of that folder ?